# Android - OnClickListeren - Button - Have to tap twice

Tags: android, events, onclick, onclicklistener

While working on a page for highscores I ran into an error..

I have 2 buttons on this page. 'Altijd' and 'Deze week'. Each button shows a different list of 'winners'.

When I want to change lists, I have to tap the other button ONCE.

When I want to change back to the first list, my first tap does nothing. To go back to my first list, I have to tap twice. If I want to go back to my second list (from my first list), I have to tap twice and so on...

Does anyone know why I have to tap twice and how I can fix it?

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Person> arrayOfPersonsAltijd = new ArrayList<Person>();
        PersonAdapter adapterAltijd = new PersonAdapter(this,arrayOfPersonsAltijd);
        ListView v = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listHighscores);

        adapterAltijd.add(new Person(1, "Naomi", 3454));
        adapterAltijd.add(new Person(2, "Steven", 2394));
        adapterAltijd.add(new Person(3, "Lieven", 2254));
        adapterAltijd.add(new Person(4, "Naomi", 3454));
        adapterAltijd.add(new Person(5, "Steven", 2394));
        v.setAdapter(adapterAltijd);


        final Button buttonWeek = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWeek);
        buttonWeek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View button) {
                // Perform action on click
                ArrayList<Person> arrayOfPersonsWekelijks = new ArrayList<Person>();
                PersonAdapter adapterWekelijks = new PersonAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayOfPersonsWekelijks);
                ListView vWeek = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listHighscores);
                adapterWekelijks.add(new Person(1, "Lieven", 3454));
                adapterWekelijks.add(new Person(2, "Meindert", 2394));
                adapterWekelijks.add(new Person(3, "Clara", 2254));
                adapterWekelijks.add(new Person(4, "Yargo", 3454));
                adapterWekelijks.add(new Person(5, "Bieke", 2394));
                vWeek.setAdapter(adapterWekelijks);
                Button buttonWekelijks = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWeek);
                buttonWekelijks.setText("- Deze week -");
                Button buttonAltijd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAltijd);
                buttonAltijd.setText("Altijd");
            }
        });

        final Button buttonAltijd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAltijd);
        buttonAltijd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View button) {
                // Perform action on click
                ArrayList<Person> arrayOfPersonsAltijd = new ArrayList<Person>();
                PersonAdapter adapterAltijd = new PersonAdapter(MainActivity.this,arrayOfPersonsAltijd);
                ListView v = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listHighscores);

                adapterAltijd.add(new Person(1, "Naomi", 3454));
                adapterAltijd.add(new Person(2, "Steven", 2394));
                adapterAltijd.add(new Person(3, "Lieven", 2254));
                adapterAltijd.add(new Person(4, "Naomi", 3454));
                adapterAltijd.add(new Person(5, "Steven", 2394));
                v.setAdapter(adapterAltijd);
                Button buttonWekelijks = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWeek);
                buttonWekelijks.setText("Deze week");
                Button buttonAltijd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAltijd);
                buttonAltijd.setText("- Altijd -");
            }
        });


    }

}
```

[image: screenshot Highscores]

Answer (score 0):

Add persons in arraylist before assigning it to adapter. like this in both onclick() methods

```
ArrayList<Person> arrayOfPersonsAltijd = new ArrayList<Person>();
            PersonAdapter adapterAltijd = new PersonAdapter(MainActivity.this,arrayOfPersonsAltijd);
            adapterAltijd.add(new Person(1, "Naomi", 3454));
            adapterAltijd.add(new Person(2, "Steven", 2394));
            adapterAltijd.add(new Person(3, "Lieven", 2254));
            adapterAltijd.add(new Person(4, "Naomi", 3454));
            adapterAltijd.add(new Person(5, "Steven", 2394));
            ListView v = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listHighscores);

            v.setAdapter(adapterAltijd);
            Button buttonWekelijks = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWeek);
            buttonWekelijks.setText("Deze week");
            Button buttonAltijd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAltijd);
            buttonAltijd.setText("- Altijd -");
```

or 
you could add `adapterWekelijks.notifyDatasetChanged();`   after  `v.setAdapter(adapterAltijd);`

Comment: I tried adding adapterWekelijks.notifyDatasetChanged(); but it doesn't solve the double click. I cannot access adapterWekelijks inside adapterAltijd

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use array list to add not the adapter.

and you can modify code to simplify like below: you can just use one adapter, use notifyDatasetChanged() to update if data set changed.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<Person> arrayOfPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    PersonAdapter adapter = new PersonAdapter(this,arrayOfPersons);
    ListView v = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listHighscores);

    arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(1, "Naomi", 3454));
    arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(2, "Steven", 2394));
    arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(3, "Lieven", 2254));
    arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(4, "Naomi", 3454));
    arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(5, "Steven", 2394));
    v.setAdapter(adapter);


    final Button buttonWeek = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWeek);
    buttonWeek.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View button) {
            // Perform action on click
            arrayOfPersons.clear();
            arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(1, "Lieven", 3454));
            arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(2, "Meindert", 2394));
            arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(3, "Clara", 2254));
            arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(4, "Yargo", 3454));
            arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(5, "Bieke", 2394));
            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
            Button buttonWekelijks = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWeek);
            buttonWekelijks.setText("- Deze week -");
            Button buttonAltijd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAltijd);
            buttonAltijd.setText("Altijd");
        }
    });

    final Button buttonAltijd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAltijd);
    buttonAltijd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View button) {
            // Perform action on click

            arrayOfPersons.clear();
            arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(1, "Naomi", 3454));
            arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(2, "Steven", 2394));
            arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(3, "Lieven", 2254));
            arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(4, "Naomi", 3454));
            arrayOfPersons.add(new Person(5, "Steven", 2394));
            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
            Button buttonWekelijks = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWeek);
            buttonWekelijks.setText("Deze week");
            Button buttonAltijd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAltijd);
            buttonAltijd.setText("- Altijd -");
        }
    });


}
```

}

hope this works !!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it didn't help :(